# Short, pulsed output circuit

Tags: circuit-design

I need to make a circuit that outputs a single, short, negative pulse of a little less than a second, no matter how long the positive input is sustained. The 1st circuit below gives me the negative output, but I don't know how to achieve a pulse. Would the second circuit work? (Kludged together from various sites.) Any help would be appreciated!
[image]

Comment: Why mess with descrete transistors (it can be done but requires experience) when it is much easier to use a 555 timer IC, read: https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/waveforms/555_timer.html and look at the "monostable 555 timer"

Comment: C1 is a differentiator which is what you'd like as a modification step. A rising edge input will temporarily pull up on the base of the BJT, driving its output into saturation if you have designed all the values correctly. Soon, C1 charges sufficiently that there's no longer a base current source and Q1 turns back off. Ignoring the individual values and assuming that you don't need a perfect square output shape, it has the right topology. It's the falling edge side that may be a problem due to the length of time it will take to 'reset' C1. A diode could help.

Comment: +1 for what @Bimpelrekkie suggested (or other one-shot device) as being easier, but just to be clear you want a negative-going pulse, but not a negative voltage pulse, correct?

Comment: What current output capability and output resistance does the sensor have?

Comment: The "next circuit" takes a connection to ground to trigger it... the first circuit above works with that, but now I need just a pulse... because, if it's 3 seconds or so, the "next circuit" moves on to a different function. Sorry I was unclear... hopefully this doesn't add more mud!

Comment: @James... 3.5 to 5 VDC. It's a small motion detector board... no info on resistance.

Comment: Sounds like you may well require a high impedance input for the pulse generator.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie... Thanks, I'll check it out.

Comment: Graphician - it sounds like the output pulse always will be shorter than the input pulse.  Is this true.  This matters because if so, the resulting circuit is a bit more simple.  Also, does the sensor output go high or low when it senses something?

Comment: -1 for what @Bimpelrekkie suggested.  A standard 555 monostable circuit does not produce a negative-going, open-collector pulse.

Comment: @AnalogKid Where does op ask for an open collector output? The schematic suggests open collector but OP asks for "negative pulse". And if an open collector is needed, that can be added with one resistor and one NPN.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using ICs instead of discrete transistors, here's something that does what you ask:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fomxWK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]
[image]

This uses one of the schmitt trigger inverters in the 74HC14. The schmitt trigger input is needed in this application because the slew rate of the charging capacitor's voltage will be too slow for a regular inverter, like the 74HC04. You could use any schmitt trigger gate, like a 74HC132 NAND gate; any of them will get you good input noise immunity, and sharp output transistions compatible with any logic inputs that follow.

The capacitor C1 is intially discharged, and when the input signal changes state (from low to high), so does the input of U1a, causing an immediate output transition too. But C1 begins to charge, and after half a second or so the U1a's input will return to its previous state, with the output switching states too. The result is a short low pulse at U1a's output.

When the input signal returns low, U1a input will go negative, and forward bias D1. C1 is then discharged immediately via D1 (which also prevents the U1a input from going more negative than -0.7V), ready for the next incoming pulse. D1 is not actually necessary, because the 74HC14's inputs already all have protection diodes that do exactly the same thing. I only include it here because it is an important part of understanding the function of the circuit.

During C1's discharge, the input signal source will suddenly be expected to sink a large current, which I mitigate with R2. This does increase the discharge time, but it's still *much* shorter than the charging time. If the sensor output is unable to sink this current, you may buffer it with another inverter, as I describe below.

In the 74HC14 you have 6 of these inverters, so you could build six of these units with a single IC.

If the inverted output pulses are a problem, then simply chain two inverters together (although now you only have 3 modules possible per IC):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFuwU8.png)</sup>

[image]

If you are worried about loading the signal from your sensor, you could modify this circuit to use one of the gates to buffer the source signal prior to the capacitive load, and perform the double inversion simultaneously:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fuE7HL.png)</sup>

This time, because the capacitor charging signal is inverted, we have to charge the capacitor with respect to the positive supply, to retain the same behaviour. The output here will be positive pulses.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Pulse generator]

SW1 and R8 represent the sensor. When SW1 opens, the "sensor output" goes high. Q1 is configured as an emitter follower (so as to be a light load on the "sensor"), and so when the "sensor output" goes high the emitter of Q1 follows it and Q2 switches on pulling its collector low. C1/R3/R4 together act as a differentiator which outputs the short negative going pulse required to trigger the 555 timer. With the correct component values you could use this negative going pulse as your output pulse and not bother with the 555 timer but the pulse will have a quite slowly rising trailing edge and so I have added the 555 timer to sharpen up the trailing edge of the pulse.

The 555 timer outputs a positive going pulse and so an inverter based around Q3 is added to invert the positive going pulse into a negative going pulse.

D1 snubs the positive going output from the differentiator, generated when the sensor's output returns to 0V.

The 7555 is a cmos based timer which is spec'd to operate down to a supply voltage of 2 V.

The negative going output pulse is about 3/4 second long and its duration is determined by the following equation:

T = 1.1 * R5 * C2

Comment: Thank you so much, James. I'll most likely pursue this... there are more components than I was hoping for, since I have to put a couple dozen of these together... but it's a solution! Thank you again!!

Comment: @Graphician There are other options. You might try and find a low/micro power comparator with voltage reference built in. These won't need many parts, are very low power if that's important, but are more boutique than using a 555 arrangement as above. You will need a resistor divider pair, at minimum. Possibly, if you want settable hysteresis as well (slow changes suggest it may be important), then another resistor pair perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

D1 isn't necessary but speed the discharge of C1 after input becomes low to be ready for next trigger. You can use a signal schottky to discharge lower (0.3v).

R4 reduces a discharging current a little to not damage a signal source(important in high caps).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4KCOt.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Yes! I wrote in a comment that, *"It's the falling edge side that may be a problem due to the length of time it will take to 'reset' C1. A diode could help."*